# How do I change the relative path of all assets for an app built with angular-cli?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

For various reasons, I need to have my index.html file for my Angular2 app separate from all the other files for the app (javascript, vendor files, assets, etc). All the other files also must live in a sub-directory on my domain. Here is an example:

```
assets/
    my_app_assets/
         main.js
         app/
         vendor/
html/
    index.html
```

I know how to tell the angular-cli build process to output the files like this, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to tell the relative paths in `index.html` to point to `domain.com/assets/my_app_assets/main.js` instead of `domain.com/main.js`.

Comment: Have you able to solve this

Answer (score 0):

## 2023

You can do this using `baseHref` (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/b09ce572ed72f19c353e71b7d9d751484c5db63a/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/builders/browser/schema.json#L267)

`deployUrl` has been deprecated by `baseHref`.

---

Credit:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3557#issuecomment-433868214

> I'm using Angular 6, and setting `--base-href` wasn't enough to solve this, but setting `deployUrl` in `angular.json` did.
>
> You can set it in `projects -> $projectName -> architect -> build -> options`.
>
> E.g.
> `"deployUrl": "/app/"`